# Spark Debug logs not showing in yarn resource manager

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I have mentioned some debug logs in my spark code which I am running through oozie.I am able to see all the INFO logs of my spark code in YARN Resource Manager but the debug logs are not coming. I got the following solution from google but it didn't work:

```
To ensure that your Spark job shows up in the Spark History Server, make sure to specify these three Spark configuration properties either in spark-opts with --conf or from oozie.service.SparkConfigurationService.spark.configurations in oozie-site.xml.

spark.yarn.historyServer.address=SPH-HOST:18088

spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://NN:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory

spark.eventLog.enabled=true
```

Anybody know how it will work ?